# Recover cut off characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Case in a production environment.

A textarea field in an internal program was set to varchar(255) in the database. However, there was no check on the length of the typed string.

Now the person that typed the string wants me to recover the cut off characters and refuses to write the string again.

There is no logging enabled on the MySQL server.

I have already set the field to longtext, but obviously the characters did not magically appear.

Does anyone know a way how to recover these cut off characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get them from MySQL, since the extra characters that wouldn't fit were discarded.

You might be able to get them from other sources - if you are doing a GET instead of a POST, the parameters of the form would be in your web server log.

Otherwise, those characters are gone.

Answer (score 0):

I think is not possible since they're truncated at insertion time.